How add a drawable shaped image background of a frame layout in android studio
Hi I am trying to set a a background of the frame layout of my app like this image
I want this type of background:

I can set the background of the frame layout in this shape but i cannot set a image with the shape in the background of layout. As you can see I have added the color with that shape in the background of the frame layout. I maded a seperate drawable file to add this shape background but I want to add this image in this shape so there are any way to add it.
Now I have this type of bg but I want to add a image at the place of this color with same style:

If any body know how to convert this black shape into the image shape please ans mee.
I want to add a image in the shape of a drawable file of android studio. I cannot find a video of this tutorial on youtube and cannot find a article on google. Everybody show how to make a imageview custum shape but I want to make a drawable xml custum image shape to add it in the background of the frame layout or other layouts. I also tried to design image in this shape and add it as a background but it not show as I want please help me to solve it.
I used this drawable code as a background to add this color background
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/black"/>

    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"/>
</shape>

And add it into my frame layout using this code using this line
android:background="@drawable/my_tabs_bg"
I try to use a line like
<solid android:drawable="@drawable/tabs_bg_img"/>

in my drawable file to set a background image but its not work. I also used chatgpt to do it. I do some servival tasks with me but all of thats not work.
I want to change a color background to a image background
